# To use or not to use ENUM/SET type?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Are you using ENUM/SET field type in your projects or you're using VARCHAR/INT field and definening available values in code? What is the best practice?

Avoiding ENUM/SET seems to me be more easy to maintain, because we have to change values only in code (not both DB and code).

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its impossible to answer this question without knowing what your project is, what your data is like, etc.

Generally speaking, its limiting to use `ENUM` and also limiting to define the values directly in your code.  If you need to make a change to either of these if requires "`ALTER`ing" a column or editing your code.  If you create a separate table to store acceptable values, and link to that table using a foreign key, you can easily add and edit attributes without having to change any of your definitions or your code.

**EDIT**: It also makes attributes accessible to your code.

Comment: After having to alter a multimillion row table to add a new ENUM value, I only use them when I know the values won't be changing like days of the week. Limiting but less painful on huge tables.

Answer (score 1):

I use enum, but for search/performance, it's better to use INT